# End a testing track in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

An APK with an incorrect build number (594 instead of 59) made it to our internal test track accidentally. I need to end the test so that I may remove the APK from my artifact library. From what I understand, you can end a test by removing the testers. So I did just that and clicked the `Remove Testers` button in the track management screen.

This seemed to work, and I got a "Changes Saved" toaster. But when I go to navigate away from the page, I get a warning telling me that changes have not been saved and that if I navigate away from the screen my changes will be lost. So if I navigate away, I lose my changes and the test is still active; but if I don't navigate away, then I don't have an option to save my changes...

How can I end a test so that I may remove the APK from my artifact library?

Answer (score 1):

I found a roundabout solution to fix this problem:

1) Create a new release but don't add a new APK/App Bundle

2) Rollout this new release to the Internal Test track

3) This rollout will deactivate the APK/App Bundle that was previously in the test track (in my case it was build 594)

4) Now you can delete the artifact from the artifact library and successfully upload a new APK into the test track that does not get blocked for having a build number lower than 594